Best practice for expanding parameters with multiple values
I have a workflow in which I expand parameters that have multiple values (i.e. param1=[A,B], param2=[1,2]). The rule produces expected results. However, I'm not sure whether I'm adhering to the best practices. In particular, I'm not sure how "readable" and explicit the rule is given that I'm expending parameters in Snakefile and reference it in the rule using wildcards. I would greatly appreciate your help and suggestions. Bellow is the workflow:
The config.yaml:
test:
  param1: [A, B]
  param2: [1, 2]

the Snakefile:
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("8.0")

configfile: "config/config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("out-param1_{p1}-param2_{p2}.txt", p1=config["test"]["param1"], p2=config["test"]["param2"]),
      
include: "rules/test_rule.smk"


the rule:
rule test_rule:
    output:
        "out-param1_{p1}-param2_{p2}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "param1 is: {wildcards.p1} param2 is: {wildcards.p2}" > {output}
        """

It produces all 4 expected output files:
out-param1_A-param2_1.txt
out-param1_A-param2_2.txt
out-param1_B-param2_1.txt
out-param1_B-param2_2.txt

Wish you a nice day

I think you are doing things right. I know it seems a bit strange that you will often start with a list of known inputs, then use expand() to decide what need to be the workflow outputs, and then construct a chain of rules with wildcard patterns allowing Snakemake to trace back from these output filenames to the original inputs. It all seems a bit circular, but this is how it works.
So carry on. I have one small suggestion but I'm not sure it actually makes the thing more readable, just a bit more concise.
rule all:
    input:
        expand("out-param1_{param1}-param2_{param2}.txt", **config["test"])


Thank you, Tim! That is reassuring.
I was not aware of this possibility **config["test"], it is useful addition.

If your workflow is small, I think it is easier to read if you directly put your "productive" rules in the main snakefile instead of using include.
Also, I would get rid of expand and generate the list of the desired final output in plain Python using list comprehension.
final output = [
    f"out-param1_{p1}-param2_{p2}.txt"
    for p1 in config["test"]["param1"]
    for p2 in config["test"]["param2"]]

rule all:
    input:
        final_output

rule test_rule:
    output:
        "out-param1_{p1}-param2_{p2}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "param1 is: {wildcards.p1} param2 is: {wildcards.p2}" > {output}
        """

In my opinion, expand is just creating confusion for beginners.
Rule inputs are files, or lists of files.
expand is just a way to create a list of files, it is not a magic trick to parallelize rule execution.
If you work with Snakemake, it can be useful in the long term to learn some general Python basics (like f-strings and list comprehensions, which is what I used to generate final_output instead of expand, which is Snakemake-specific).
The "magic" is in the way inputs from a rule are matched with outputs of other rules to determine which rules need to be executed, and with what wildcard values.
Here, final_output is evaluated as a list of 4 file names, so to satisfy the input of rule all, snakemake figures out that those file names can be matched against the output pattern of rule test_rule. This triggers the execution of 4 instances of test_rule, with the values for wildcards.p1 and wildcards.p2 inferred each time based on the correspondence between the desired file's name and the "out-param1_{p1}-param2_{p2}.txt" pattern.
